# Make radio button checkd by default

Tags: angular, angular7

I have implented 2 radio button for male and female and I want to make the first radio button checked by default.

I already added the checked property of radio button but still it is displaying unchecked

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" [(ngModel)]="data.gender" #gender="ngModel" [checked]>
   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Male</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" [(ngModel)]="data.gender" #gender="ngModel">
   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Female</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove that `[]` from checked attribute

Comment: ```checked``` attribute must be without brackets in your case. Square brackets in angular used for property binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your typescript,

Store `data.gender = "male"`

and remove `checked` attribute from HTML. By using above approach your checked value must be always updated *[as shown in the example]*.

[`Live_Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfktgp-zjuy76)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[(ngModel)]`, but you'll need to update your value to `data.gender` with "male", remove `[]` from checked.